# Unable to find the error in this basic Qt snippet, but I am told that it exists for sure?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I've been recently trying to get into Qt to better understand class hierarchy and OOP. I just fell upon this question in a test bank, asking to "fix" this code to prevent compiler and runtime errors. However, I unfortunately couldn't find the solution and I wasn't able to come up with a solution myself. For me, all QObject-derived classes handle all memory deallocation. So the following code does not pose any problems that I can see, and it compiles.

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel label("my string");
    QWidget window;
    label.setParent(&window);
    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: change to `QLabel *label = new QLabel("my string")` `label->setParent(&window);`

Comment: Hi, @eyllanesc thank you for your answer. But I still don't see the problem. Both builds give me the same output, and I see no difference other than the fact that QLabel is dynamically allocated. Which changes nothing with regard to the application, or am I wrong?

Comment: A QObject when it is eliminated also eliminates its children, so QWidget when it is destroyed also destroys QLabel, but QLabel is also eliminated when the application is finished since it is a local variable, so you have double elimination so in the second deletion deletes an unallocated memory. Now you see the problem? So that behavior is expected by the architecture of Qt.

Answer (score 2):

> For me, all QObject-derived classes handle all memory deallocation.

Exactly, that's why this sample code contains an error of the kind you'll see when you close `window`. Qt's parent-children system works in the way that the widget manages it's children's lifetime and deletes them when being deleted itself.

So, when `QApplication` quits `~QWidget()` destructor is called, causing deletion of the `label`. Thus, `~QLabel()` is called.

But on the other hand, when `main` is finished, local variables are being deleted, `label` is one of them. It is not a pointer but a value variable, we get another call of `~QLabel()`.

Double call of the destructor is the error. It can be fixed by creating `label` on a heap via `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Qt handles memory management by parent-child relationships. If a parent widget/window is destroyed, it destroys all the children as well. In this instance the label is set as a child of the window, which means that the windows destructor will try to delete it. As it is create on the stack, the memory deallocation will fail. And even if it will not (assuming the memory manger silently ignores such call, which it should not), the label will be destroyed the second time when the execution of `main()` finishes, leading to double-delete. As others have already pointed out, you could solve it by allocating the label on the heap using `QLabel *label = new QLabel("my string");` instead, but there is an even simpler solution: re-order the creation of the window and the label:

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    QLabel label("my string");
    label.setParent(&window);
    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This way the label will be destroyed before the window. That will remove the label from the windows children list and allow correct termination.

Finally, the use of the `setParent()` method is actually relatively rare in Qt. Normally you would have passed the parent to the constructor of the child widget:

```
QWidget window;
QLabel label("my string", &window); // No need for setParent()
```

This requires that the window already exists, and is Qt-s way of leading you towards the correct solution.